# How to reduce left and bottom space from toolbar title in collapsing action bar android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image]
[image]

I need to reduce  left and bottom space from toolbar title in collapsing action bar. I need to do something like whats app. Here is my code.
Thanks for help.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/speaker1"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Did you tried `expandedTitleMarginStart` & `expandedTitleMarginBottom`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it is not working.

Comment: You need to add those attributes in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as ` app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="8dp"` and `app:expandedTitleMarginStart="8dp"` (make `8dp` what you want.) That should work.

Comment: Thank you cheticamp for help. It's working.

Answer (score 3):

add this below in your activity where you are setting the title

```
 mBinding.collapseToolbar.setExpandedTitleMarginBottom((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.contact_info_expanded_title_margin));
 mBinding.collapseToolbar.setExpandedTitleMarginStart((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.contact_info_expanded_title_margin));

mBinding.collapseToolbar.setTitle("Toolbar title");
```